# Smarty variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I am really starting with Smarty and I do not understand this fact:

if I put the next code inside my template index.tpl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toAlert() {
    alert('{$text}' );
  }
</script>
```

I can access to the function toAlert and show the content of Smarty variable {{$text}}, but if I put this code into a js file lije javascript.js and I try to access it by putting into de template the link:

I cannot access to the function as well.

Can anyone tell me why or help wher can I find this specific info? thank you!!

Comment: php executes before the page is loaded, so the js above actually looks like alert('theactualvalueof$text');. Therefor it cant work the other way arround, as php has already beed parsed when js runs

Comment: What I finally did was to load the PHP texts n the javaScript variables in the temaplate, like this: var text = '{$text}'; and then I could use the javascript variable text inside the <script> file loaded after the PHP code.

Comment: Yes, thats a good solution. Storing them as properties of an object instead of individual variables might be a little cleaner, eg `var data = { text: '{$text}', other: '{$other}'};` Then you can access `alert(data.text + ' ' + data.other);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smarty 2 requires escaping of the "{" and "}" characters, you can use {ldelim} and {rdelim} to escape them individually or wrap entire blocks of text with {literal}{/literal}. It's usually cleaner to use {ldelim} and {rdelim} when there is embedded smarty tags, so example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toAlert() {ldelim}
    alert('{$text}');
  {rdelim}
</script>
```

Smarty 3 conveniently ignores "{" and "}" characters surrounded by white space, so your javascript example would work as-is.

Comment: There is a typo in `{redlim}`. Should be `{rdelim}`.

Answer (score 3):

You should put this code intp TPL file to make this work. Only TPL files are processed as Smarty files and you can use there Smarty variables.

Your code put should work out of the box in your index.tpl file but if it weren't try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
  function toAlert() {
    alert('{/literal}{$text}{literal}' );
  }
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: You are putting wrong '/' in alert literal 

<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
  function toAlert() {
    alert('{literal}{$text}{/literal}' );
  }
{/literal}
</script>